# Drop rows in pandas if null values condition met

Tags: pandas

How to remove the rows if the nan values count is greater than equal (>=) to 5?

#### DataFrame looks like this :

| user_id | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | b5 | b6 | b7 | b8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 6 |
| 3 | NaN | 1 | NaN | 2 | NaN | 3 | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | NaN | 5 | 2 | 7 | 6 |
| 5 | NaN | 3 | 2 | NaN | 4 | 1 | 5 | NaN |
| 6 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leverage `isna()` to identify the NaNs and then `sum()` those with `axis=1` to get the NaN count per row.  Then use that as a (negated) mask to keep the rows you want.

```
dfd = df.loc[~(df.isna().sum(axis=1)>=5)]
print(dfd)
```

**Result**

```
          bl   b2   b3   b4   b5   b6   b7   b8
user_id                                        
2        1.0  3.0  4.0  2.0  5.0  7.0  8.0  6.0
4        1.0  3.0  4.0  NaN  5.0  2.0  7.0  6.0
5        NaN  3.0  2.0  NaN  4.0  1.0  5.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

The `thresh` parameter in `dropna()` can be used for this. This parameter looks at the count of non NaN values, and will drop the row if there is not at least that many values present.

For this problem, since there are 8 columns, using a `thresh` of 4 will make sure that at most only 4 NaN values can exist in each row.

```
df.dropna(thresh = 4)
```